# Amplify React App Stuck Running Tests and Never Deploys

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I feel like I'm missing something simple but I can't find anything on the web on what I'm doing wrong. Here's my yml file

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm test --watchAll=false && npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

It's basically the default but I want tests (and eventual a coverage report) to run before moving on to the next step. Currently it just sits there after spitting out: "No tests found related to files changed since last commit."

I want all tests to run every single time and for the deployment to complete. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I change my tests to this:

```
npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false
```

Now the tests run and everything continues as normal.